# Visual studio2013 need to remove text from properties

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Trying to remove `WIF1.2.10` from property

**EDITED**

From:

```
QuestionText = "WIF1.1 First Name",
QuestionText = "WIF1.2.10 Middle Name",
QuestionText = "WIF15 Notes to solicitor",
```

To:

```
QuestionText = "First Name",
QuestionText = "Middle Name",
QuestionText = "Notes to solicitor",
```

tried so far

From:

```
QuestionText = "(WIF{\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}}) (.*)",
```

Replace with

```
QuestionText = "$2",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the curly braces in your regex and make the decimal part as optional.

```
QuestionText = "(WIF\d{1,2}(?:(?:\.\d{1,2})?\.\d{1,2})?) ([^"]*)",
```

Replacement string:

```
QuestionText = "$2",
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/11)

Comment: Edited, I was missing 2 more cases I think